# Apache Camel FOP component config file location

Tags: java, apache-camel, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'd like to configure Apache Camel FOP component to use configuration file (as described [here](http://camel.apache.org/fop.html#FOP-EndpointOptions)). It seems Camel is looking for the file in server base path, because I got exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\Eclipse\eclipse\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\fop.xml
```

What I want is to store configuration file path in classpath along with other configuration files.

Here is Camel route:

```
from("direct:renderer").routeId("direct:renderer")
        .onException(Exception.class)
            // Exception handling
        .end()

        // I want fop.xml config file to be looked for in classpath
        .to("fop:application/pdf?userConfigURL=src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/fop.xml") 
        .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${property.job.id}.pdf"))
        .to("file:eiocha/pdf")
```

I'm using Apache Camel of version 2.10.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I logged a ticket to improve camel-fop, so the useConfigURL option can be loaded from classpath and whatnot: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6103

Comment: Where could I find example of Resource Helper Api usage?

Answer (score 0):

Camel supports only endpoints configured with a starting directory. So the directoryName must be a directory.

[Reference](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: In my case `eiocha/pdf` is a directory. File name is set using `CamelFileName` header. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: The problem is not with file component, it works. Even fop component works nice without `userConfigURL` option